# ¿Cómo inhabilitar un campo dependiendo de lo que se haya colocado en otra opción en un formulario?

Tags: html

Tengo el siguiente formulario sencillo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Insertar datos</title>
  </head>
  <style media="screen">

  </style>
  <body>
    <h1>Inserción de productos</h1> <br/>
    <form action="validarInsercionDatos.php" name="insercion">
      Código <input type="text" name="codigo"><br><br>
      Sección: <input type="text" name="seccion"><br><br>
      Nombre <input type="text" name="nombre"><br><br>
      Precio <input type="text" name=""><br><br>
      Fecha <input type="text" name=""><br><br>
      Importado <select class="" name="importado">
                     <option value="si">Si</option>
                     <option value="No">No</option>
                </select><br><br>
      País de origen <input type="text" name=""><br><br>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lo que quiero es que al darle la opción no en el campo importado me inhabilite o desaparezca la opción país de orígen. Estaré investigando en internet pero agradezco su colaboración.

Answer (score 0):

Una respuesta sencilla:

Usar jQuery aunque no es una obligacion, y utilizar el vento `change`

si quieres algo mas complejo lees el option del select y ya, pero te dejo un ejemplo basico

```js
$("#importado").change(function(){
if ($("#importado").val() == 'si')
    $("#pais").show();
else {
$("#pais").hide();
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Insertar datos</title>
  </head>
  <style media="screen">

  </style>
  <body>
    <h1>Inserción de productos</h1> <br/>
    <form action="validarInsercionDatos.php" name="insercion">
      Código <input type="text" name="codigo"><br><br>
      Sección: <input type="text" name="seccion"><br><br>
      Nombre <input type="text" name="nombre"><br><br>
      Precio <input type="text" name=""><br><br>
      Fecha <input type="text" name=""><br><br>
      Importado <select class="" id="importado">
                     <option value="si">Si</option>
                     <option value="No">No</option>
                </select><br><br>
                <div id="pais">
      País de origen <input type="text" name=""><br><br></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola amigo. Lo que pasa es que javascript lo iniciaré pronto. me imagino que el código donde llamas la función es de js?